# Writing shell script to build and deploy WAR file

Tags: java, tomcat, war

Bear with me as this is my first java servlet using Tomcat. I wrote it in Eclipse on Windows, and need to write a build script and run script for it.

From what I'm told, the user who I send this to will need to have Tomcat installed in order to run this WAR.

If that's the case, my build script will need to 
1. Install tomcat on their laptop
2. Deploy my war to it

and my run script just needs to run my program?

Comment: Are you going to support individuals/organizations that already have a tomcat instance installed? Another approach is to not attempt to install tomcat *per se*, but make a .zip/.tar.gz that has tomcat and your application already deployed within it. Then simply extract the .zip/.tar.gz and start tomcat. This approach is used by, e.g., Atlassian for their tomcat projects.

Comment: Tried Spring Boot? Goto start.spring.io and select the technologies you need. Create and download the project in maven format (pom.xml project file) Build and distribute a runnable jar file with your servlet and tomcat embedded. Your jar can even be turned into a "real" executable (in reality your jar is embedded into a shell script so that you can start it from the command line without using "java -jar ..."), and you can easily install it as a service/daemon. This is by far the easiest way to go about this.

Comment: @jonmartinsolaas Nice! I'll look into this. Will this work if the user doesn't have tomcat installed though? If tomcat is embedded in my jar, would it just run or would the user still need to install tomcat on their machine before running my program?

Comment: @KevinO This would only work if the user already has tomcat installed right?

Comment: For the Atlassian products, we get a tarball that when expanded has a tomcat instance with the product .war already in the correct location to deploy. Untar, and run bin/startup.sh -- done. However, many organizations already have a tomcat (or other JEE system), and would prefer to obtain a .war (or .ear) to they can just add to their existing farm. So in the case of the tarball, no the customer does not need tomcat installed. In the latter case, it is part of a larger organizational infrastructure.

Comment: If I embed tomcat into my java application (which seems like what both solutions above are trying to do), and the user doesn't have tomcat installed on their computer, would it still work? I looked at a tutorial about embedding tomcat into a java web application, but it seems like the code calls "startTomCatInstance" or something along those lines. I wouldn't think this would work if the user doesn't have tomcat installed right?

Comment: @Kevin tomcat and all other deps are embedded in the jar, only java is needed.

Comment: @Kevin - PS, there is a lot of stuff going on behind the scenes with Spring Boot. For instance Tomcat is started for you when the application is started. You can exclude most of it, but still it'd be a Spring app with class path scan, dependency injection and so on.  If you don't want or need this, I'd recommend the "Atlasssian way". Otherwise - dive in and use as much of it as you can :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this can help you :
**https://gist.github.com/geowa4/1428257**

```
#!/bin/bash
TOMCAT=apache-tomcat-7.0.23
TOMCAT_WEBAPPS=$TOMCAT/webapps
TOMCAT_CONFIG=$TOMCAT/conf/server.xml
TOMCAT_START=$TOMCAT/bin/startup.sh
TOMCAT_ARCHIVE=$TOMCAT.tar.gz
TOMCAT_URL=http://apache.mirrorcatalogs.com/tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.23/bin/$TOMCAT_ARCHIVE
WAR_FILE=whatever.war

if [ ! -e $TOMCAT ]; then
if [ ! -r $TOMCAT_ARCHIVE ]; then
if [ -n "$(which curl)" ]; then
    curl -O $TOMCAT_URL
elif [ -n "$(which wget)" ]; then
    wget $TOMCAT_URL
fi
fi

if [ ! -r $TOMCAT_ARCHIVE ]; then
echo "Tomcat could not be downloaded." 1>&2
echo "Verify that eiter curl or wget is installed." 1>&2
echo "If they are, check your internet connection and try again." 1>&2
echo "You may also download $TOMCAT_ARCHIVE and place it in this folder."  1>&2
exit 1
fi

tar -zxf $TOMCAT_ARCHIVE
rm $TOMCAT_ARCHIVE
fi

if [ ! -w $TOMCAT -o ! -w $TOMCAT_WEBAPPS ]; then
echo "$TOMCAT and $TOMCAT_WEBAPPS must be writable." 1>&2
exit 1
fi

if [ ! -r $WAR_FILE ]; then
echo "$WAR_FILE is missing. Download it and run this again to deploy it." 1>&2
else
cp $WAR_FILE $TOMCAT_WEBAPPS
fi
```

This is a sh file, so you could use in Linux.